# How does DataMapper's auto_upgrade work?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, database-migration, ruby-datamapper

Can you please tell me how Data Mapper's auto upgrade thing works?

For example:

```
include 'data_mapper'
DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/base.db"

class User
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id, Serial
   property :name, String
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Here, how does that Data Mapper's auto upgrade understand that they have to create a Data Base

Comment: It just checks whether the database exists and if not, creates it. I dont get the question.

Comment: how does it understand that the User class is a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the User class is *not* a database, it is a *model*, which is linked to a *table* in a *database*.

When you `include DataMapper::Resource`, it will automatically call `extend DataMapper::Model`:

```
# https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/resource.rb#L55-L58

module DataMapper
  module Resource
    # ...

    def self.included(model)
      model.extend Model
      super
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

this call to extend is intercepted by another hook in `DataMapper::Model`, which keeps track of the module's descendants:

```
# https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/model.rb#L209-L223

module DataMapper
  module Model
    # ...

    def self.descendants
      @descendants ||= DescendantSet.new
    end

    # ...

    def self.extended(descendant)
      descendants << descendant
      # ...
      super
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

later, DataMapper can find all models via `DataMapper::Model.descendants`:

```
# https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations/blob/8bfcec08286a12ceee1bc3e5a01da3b5b7d4a74d/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb#L43-L50

module DataMapper
  module Migrations
    module SingletonMethods
      # ...

      def auto_upgrade!(repository_name = nil)
        repository_execute(:auto_upgrade!, repository_name)
      end

      # ...

      def repository_execute(method, repository_name)
        models = DataMapper::Model.descendants
        models = models.select { |m| m.default_repository_name == repository_name } if repository_name
        models.each do |model|
          model.send(method, model.default_repository_name)
        end
      end

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
module Model
  def self.descendants
    @descendants ||= []
  end

  def self.extended(base)
    descendants << base
    super
  end
end

module Resource
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(Model)
  end
end

class Car
  include Resource
end

class Bike
  include Resource
end

class Train
  include Resource
end

Model.descendants
#=> [Car, Bike, Train]
```